# PHP optimize code

Tags: php

Several questions on "**what is the shortest code for this?**":

1. Without {}

   ```
   if($match->name == "Marry") {
       $match = true;
   }
   ```
2. Without {}

   ```
   if($match->name == "Marry") {
       $match = true;
   } else {
       $match = false;
   }
   ```
3. How to ask `if $match = true`?
4. How to ask `if array() has any value`?
5. How to ask `if $variable has numeric value` (0-9)?
6. How to ask `if $variable's first symbol isn't a letter or number`?
7. How to ask `if $match = false`?

Comment: optimize for minimum size of bytecode in memory? fastest execution? or fewest number of characters for developer to type?

Comment: Please let it be _'optimized for easy understanding by other coders in the project'_. The number of time I had to decipher a _'see I can do this in 1 line of code!'_ nonsense aren't funny. Then again, I was usually the one having put the 1-line spaghetti there in my earlier days / years. Serves me right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
$match = ($match->name == "Marry") ? true : $match;
```

2)

```
$match = ($match->name == "Marry");
```

3)

```
if ( $match === true ) {}
```

4)

```
$array = array();
if ( !empty( $array ) ) {}
```

5)

```
if ( is_numeric( $variable ) ) {}
```

6)

```
if ( ctype_alnum($variable[0]) ) ) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

1)

```
if($match->name == "Marry") {
    $match = true;
}
```

This is already short enough, you can't change it without hurting readibility (apart from maybe removing the braces).

2)

```
$match = ($match->name == "Marry");
```

Note you're using the same variable name.

3)

```
if ($match = true)
```

I suppose you want `if ($match == true)`, which should be written just `if ($match)`.

4)

(**EDIT** I read this as "has any (=some) value in particular", to check if the array is empty you can use [`empty`](http://php.net/empty))

See [`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array).

5)

There are several ways, a possible one is

```
is_numeric($variable) && strlen("$variable") == 1
```

To allow starting 0s you could do

```
is_numeric($variable) && $variable >= 0 && $variable <= 9
```

6)

```
ctype_alnum($variable[0])
```

Comment: 1 and 2 should be `Withous {}`.

Comment: Technically you can remove the {}'s from an if block consisting of a single line. But I disagree with hsz. Missing them leads to headaches with strange code functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A1. Can't really be shortened, accept in the case of part 2

A2.
    $match = ($match->name == "Marry");

A3. I suspect you mean...

```
if ($match) {
   echo "Value of $match evaluates as true";
}
```

A4. Not sure if you mean...

```
if (empty($array)) {
// or 
if (in_array($variable, $array)) {
```

A5.

```
if (is_numeric($variable)) {
   echo "it's numeric";
}
```

A6.

```
if (preg_match('#^[^a-z\d]#i', $variable) {
   echo "doesn't start with letter or number";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1) OK
2) $match = ($match->name == 'Marry';
3) if ($match)
4) if (count($array))
5) preg_match('/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?$/', $string)
6) preg_match('/^[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', $string)
```